# Translation is stuck in increments, how do I set back to free movement?

Tags: transforms

I am a beginner.

I am trying to translate in the Z axis, the problem is that I only want to translate less than a square but when I move the mouse, it translate 1 full square.

How I can deactivate the option, to move the object free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enabled snap. You can disable it with this small magnet button:
[image]

Comment: Your welcome :)